# Как можно использовать эти данные о wifi (точке доступа)?

Tags: wifi

наткнулся на данное приложение на гитхабе, но не очень понимаю функционал. что за -0.3m в правой части второй строки? и что за канал, в котором в данный момент транслирует wifi роутер?

[image: данные о wifi]

Comment: Эта информация, например, может помочь Вам выбрать оптимальный канал для вещания Вашего роутера.

Comment: С моделью OSI ознакомьтесь, а также с работой протоколов необходимых для осуществления беспроводной связи и всё станет понятно.

Answer (score 0):

`~0.3m` - это, скорее всего, примерное расстояние до точки доступа.

Канал - это частота на которой работает роутер. Её можно менять на своё усмотрение, некоторые роутеры выбирают канал автоматически.

*Диаграмма перекрытия каналов на частоте 2.4Ghz:*

[image: Диаграмма перекрытия каналов Wi-Fi]

Comment: Спасибо, а можете объяснить более подробно относительно каналов? роутер, получается, работает на нескольких каналах (частотах)? и какое это дает преимущество?

Comment: @ИванРепенцев Каждый роутер работает на своём канале (на одном), то есть на определённой частоте. Если 2 роутера будут работать на одинаковом канале, то они будут создавать для друг друга помехи. Чтобы избежать помех и увеличить качество соединения, желательно выбирать наименее загруженный непересекающийся канал (1, 6, 11). Увы, на картинке, которую Вы прикрепили, все хорошие каналы заняты, поэтому полностью избежать пересечения не получится. Подробнее можете почитать о каналах и настройке роутера [тут](https://habr.com/ru/post/117761/) и [тут](https://habr.com/ru/post/317220/) (habr.com)